# Cloning a USB flash drive to another larger one, is it safe to do so?

Tags: windows-xp, images, usb-flash-drive, clone, drive-letter

I used [Acronis True Image Home 2010](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/) to clone a Dane-Elec zLight 8Gb pen drive/USB flash drive to a PNY Attaché 16Gb USB flash drive. Now WinXP shows the drive in device manager as *USB DISK 2.0 USB DEVICE* but doesn't have it in *My Computer*/doesn't  assign it a drive letter.

What is it that has messed up the PNY Attaché and is there some way to repair it so that it can be used as a regular USB flash drive again?

Is there a safe way to clone a USB flash drive to another larger one?

How safe is it to backup and restore a USB flash drive to/from a drive-image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked that windows is *unable* to assign a drive letter?

1. Control Panel->Administrative
   tools->Computer
   Management->Storage->DiskManagement
2. Find usb pen drive in lower middle
   panel [Labeled **Disk n** (where n
   is a number) Removable 8GB]
3. right click on it and select *Change
   Drive Letter and Paths* and see if
   the assigned one is conflicting with
   another drive

In answer to the how safe is it part, True image is an excelent piece of software, and shouldn't give you any problems even if you were going from a *larger* medium to a smaller one (as long as the data itself should actually fit) though i've not used 2010 home.

I theory it shouldn't be any problem at all apart from the drive letter one you've found, but that's a windows/cloning issue, not a acronis/flash/cloning issue